# unable to access jarfile windows-service-wrapper-*.jar

Tags: windows, installation, neo4j

I have just installed neo4j release 1.8.1 on my windows computer. The readme file says I should now navigate to the install directory and type:

`C:\Tmp>bin\neo4j.bat`

But I get the following error message:

`Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Tmp\bin\windows-service-wrapper-*.jar`

Even though the bin directory does contain the file windows-service-wrapper-4.jar

I'm new to this. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Just edit **\bin\base.bat** and replace

`set wrapperJarFilename=windows-service-wrapper-*.jar`

to

`set wrapperJarFilename=windows-service-wrapper-4.jar`

Comment: it works! it's weird that they don't tell about this change in the documentations...